# Dividing by $\sqrt n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Why is the following equality true?

I know I should divide by $\sqrt n$ but how is it done exactly to get the RHS?

$$ \frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n + \sqrt n}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^3}}}}}$$

Comment: Why on earth would you tag this with [cardinals]?

Comment: Oops. I ment radicals (You sound mad)

Comment: Not mad, just flabbergasted... :-)

Comment: LHS is not equal to RHS, i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is calculus. As you said yourself, you divide the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{n}$

for the numerator it's easy, as $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}=1$.

for the denominator you get \begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{n+{\sqrt{n+{\sqrt{n}}}}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}{n}}
\end{equation}

Keep in mind, if you want to pull a factor under a square root, you have to square it!

the above can be rewritten as \begin{equation}
\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n^2}+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}}}= \sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n^4}}}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^3}}}}
\end{equation}

And you're done

Comment: Everyone were very helpful, but I liked yours the most since it was understandable and straightforward. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: How is this calculus?

Comment: I meant algebra, sorry about that, I'm not a native speaker. But after all the math is correct ;)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $n>0$.
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{ \sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}} } = \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left( \sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}} \right) } = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{n} \left( \sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} \right) } } = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \sqrt{n} } } } = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n} + \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n^3}} } } } $$.

Answer (score 4):

I find this easier to visualize if I write this problem in terms of powers:
$$\dfrac{n^{1/2}}{\left[n + \left(n + n^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}\right]^{1/2}}\text{.} $$
Division by $n^{1/2}$ for both the numerator and denominator turns the numerator into $1$ and the denominator into
$$\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\left[n + \left(n + n^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}\right]^{1/2}}{n^{1/2}} &= \left[\dfrac{n + \left(n + n^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}}{n}\right]^{1/2}\quad \text{ since }\dfrac{a^c}{b^c} = \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^{c} \\
&= \left[\dfrac{n}{n} + \dfrac{\left(n+n^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}}{n}\right]^{1/2} \quad \text{ since }\dfrac{a+b}{c} = \dfrac{a}{c} + \dfrac{b}{c} \\
&= \left[1 + \dfrac{\left(n+n^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}}{n}\right]^{1/2} \\
&= \left[1 + \dfrac{\left(n+n^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}}{\left(n^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right]^{1/2} \\
&= \left[1 + \left(\dfrac{n+n^{1/2}}{n^{2}}\right)^{1/2}\right]^{1/2} \text{ since }\dfrac{a^c}{b^c} = \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^{c} \\
&= \left[1 + \left(\dfrac{n}{n^2}+\dfrac{n^{1/2}}{n^2}\right)^{1/2}\right]^{1/2} \text{ since }\dfrac{a+b}{c} = \dfrac{a}{c} + \dfrac{b}{c} \\
&= \left[1 + \left(\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)^{1/2}\right]^{1/2} \text{ since }\dfrac{a^b}{a^c} = a^{b-c} \\
&= \left\{1 + \left[\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1^{1/2}}{(n^{3})^{1/2}}\right]^{1/2}\right\}^{1/2} \\
&= \left\{1 + \left[\dfrac{1}{n}+\left(\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)^{1/2}\right]^{1/2}\right\}^{1/2} \\
&= \sqrt{1+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n^3}}}}\text{.}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Alternate form**:

$$\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{ \sqrt{n}}}{\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}}{\sqrt{n}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}{n}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}{n}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n}}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}{ \sqrt{n}}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sqrt{\frac{n+\sqrt{n}}{n}}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}}} $$

Comment: very thorough, nice.

Comment: Except that is not the question, and the equality in the question is true. So this is an alternate form, but still not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes,you are right...

Answer (score 3):

Slightly modifying the answer from @evinda:

$\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{ \sqrt{n}}}{\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}}{\sqrt{n}}}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}{n}}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}{n}}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{\frac{n+\sqrt{n}}{n^2}}}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{\frac1n+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}}}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{\frac1n+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n^4}}}}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{\frac1n+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^3}}}}}
\end{align}$